# Error in response to storage.get: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, html

Hi There Can Anyone tell me how to solve this error:

Error in response to storage.get: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://nkeimhogjdpnpccoofpliimaahmaaome/js/content.js:1:50)
    at chrome-extension://nkeimhogjdpnpccoofpliimaahmaaome/js/content.js:1:22
/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
I have tried many times to remove it but can't.
Here is my main.html code:

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src = "angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng app = "myApp" ng-controller = "bookController">
    <form>
Book Name:-<input type="text" ng-model="bname" />
Book Author:-<input type="text" ng-model="bauthor" />
Book Price:-<input type="text" ng-model="bprice" />
Book Language:-<input type="text" ng-model="blanguage" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="insertData()" />
</form>
</div>
<script>
     var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('bookController',function($scope,$http){ 
    $scope.insertData=function(){       
    $http.post("insert.php", {
        'bname':$scope.bname,
        'bauthor':$scope.bauthor,
        'bprice':$scope.bprice,
        'blanguage':$scope.blanguage})

    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
    console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
    });
        }
         });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my insert.php code:

```
<?php 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$bname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->bname);
$bauthor = mysql_real_escape_string($data->bauthor);
$bprice = mysql_real_escape_string($data->bprice);
$blanguage = mysql_real_escape_string($data->blanguage);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root"); 
mysql_select_db("books-library");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO books('book-name', 'book-author', 'book-price', 'book-longuage') VALUES('".$bname."','".$bauthor."','".$bprice."','".$blanguage."')");
?>
```

Comment: I want to insert the data in database using angular.

Comment: Don't quote the column names in your insert query with  `'`. They have dashes, so they do need to be quoted, but use backticks instead of single quotes. Single quotes mean string literals, not identifiers.

Comment: Looks like invalid  path for script

Comment: Do you know what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)?

Comment: The error is from Chrome extension. You obviously don't write one. And you don't have storage.get in your code. What did make you think that these things are related?

Comment: Any suggestions to remove the error instead of criticizing LOL? @estus?

Comment: Script path is prefect no issue with that @instead

Comment: Whenever i open any files without localhost it works just fine.but when i use local host (Obviously I need localhost for php files) That error in console occurs.@estus

Comment: For every file I open with localhost that error occurs.@estus

Comment: No suggestions. The question cannot get an answer in it's current state. It's off-topic and can be closed because it doesn't contain a clear definition of problem (errors in console are caused by Chrome extension and look totally irrelevant) and doesn't contain http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Then How I solve the chrome extension error @estus ?

Comment: You likely shouldn't, it's irrelevant. So the question contains no clues on what's wrong.